# Slicing a Python list based on ending with one of a set of substrings

Tags: python, list

I have a python list

```
list1 = ['TC_TEST1', 'TC_TEST1_TEST2', 'TC_TEST3', 'TC_TEST1TEST2']

sublist1 = ['TEST1', 'TEST3']
```

Desired output is

```
result = ['TC_TEST1', 'TC_TEST3']
```

It should not contain patterns in sublist1 that occur in middle or other places in the string.

I tried using

```
result = [s for s in list1 if any(xs in s for xs in sublist1)]
```

but this also prints the patterns wherever it occurs in the string, not only the ending part.

Comment: you need `result = [s for s in list1 if any("TC_"+xs == s for xs in sublist1)]` then. You have to add the TC_ prefix to desambiguate.

Comment: You have two *set*s - not *list*s. Have you looked at `str.endswith` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **in** use endswith() function so just replace `result = [s for s in list1 if any(xs in s for xs in sublist1)]`
 with `result = [s for s in list1 if any(s.endswith(xs) for xs in sublist1)],`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
list1 = {'TC_TEST1', 'TC_TEST1_TEST2', 'TC_TEST3', 'TC_TEST1TEST2'}
sublist1 = { 'TEST1', 'TEST3'}
final_list = [i for i in list1 if any(i.endswith(b) for b in sublist1)]
```

Output:

```
set(['TC_TEST3', 'TC_TEST1'])
```

Advanced feature with tuples:

```
sublist1 = ('TEST1', 'TEST3')
final_list = [i for i in list1 if i.endswith(sublist1)]
```

Comment: Or just change to be: `sublist1 = ('TEST1', 'TEST3')` so it's a tuple and then your list-comp becomes: `final_list = [i for i in list1 if i.endswith(sublist1)]`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to notice that you haven't defined python lists, but *sets*. These are the equivalent lists derived from your defined sets (notice the `[]`notation):

```
list1 = ['TC_TEST1TEST2', 'TC_TEST3', 'TC_TEST1', 'TC_TEST1_TEST2']
sublist1 = ['TEST1', 'TEST3']
```

If you need to filter the strings that only ends with a list of possible substrings, you can call the `endswith` method of a Python string passing a tuple of strings as an argument. That way, your desired output can be derived using the following expression:

```
result = [s for s in list1 if s.endswith(tuple(sublist1))]
```

Actual output is:

```
>>> result
['TC_TEST3', 'TC_TEST1']
```

Comment: I would convert to `tuple` outside the listcomp so it doesn't do that at each iteration